# Adding a shadow to a image in WordPress Gutenberg Image block

Tags: css, image, wordpress-gutenberg

CSS

```
.ts-learn-img figure:hover{
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #000000;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #000000;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wp-block-image ts-learn-img">
    <figure class="aligncenter size-medium is-resized">
        <a href="https">
            <img src="https" alt="" class="wp-image-4076" width="225" height="60" srcset="https">
        </a>
    </figure>
</div>
```

This is a standard image block in Wordpress (Gutenberg) with a class specified for the block (`ts-learn-img`). I am trying to add a shadow around the image when the mouse hovers over it. But I am getting:

[image]

It is only adding a shadow on the base line. Now, I have tried using in the CSS:

- `.ts-learn-img figure a img:hover`

And it made no difference. Is it not possible to have a complete shading of some kind when the mouse hovers over the image?

The actual webpage is [here](https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk).

Comment: Remove blank space from the image and remove inset from `box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #000`

Comment: Did you update the image without any white spacing?

Comment: @MehmoodAhmad It seems to be the anchor `a` object that is below the image that is about 20px high and that is what the apparent gap is. But i can't work out how to change that.

Comment: Actually the image that you use have a transparent space in it, strip your image and use the one that have no transparent space in it.

Ideally you should use CSS for styling buttons not images.

Comment: @MehmoodAhmad I had edited the image last night to have no transparent data. It is improved now but there is sill the A area below.

Comment: Use `display: block` on img elements and set border radius of `figure` elements. That will solve your problem.

Comment: @MehmoodAhmad It is working. Thanks. I have removed some of the comments from here. Maybe you can reduce yours too to the important ones. I have added an answer based on your comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments provided, the following steps were required:

1. I had to remove the excess transparency from around the image so that it was just the button.
2. I had to make changes to the CSS styles as follows:

```
.ts-learn-img figure {
    -moz-border-radius: 5px !important;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px !important;
    border-radius: 5px !important;
}

.ts-learn-img img {
  display: block;   
}

.ts-learn-img figure:hover{
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px #000;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px #000;

}
```

Now it looks much better!

[image: New Button]